# disclosure indicator moves cell subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with some cells using a disclosure indicator and some not.

Obviously the disclosure indicator scrunches the contents so not all of the cells line up together in perfect columns.

How can I adjust my contents to stay in the same location regardless of there being a disclosure indicator or not?

Comment: Show some code. Using the standard text label or custom? Any images?

Comment: Just basic text labels.  Nothing fancy.  No code because its in XIB

Comment: There must be something you are doing to show and hide the disclosure indicator?

Comment: well yes, if there is a property set in the object I use to fill the text data, I show the indicator.  If not I don't.  But thats not really my question, I need to know if its possible to keep the labels from adjusting their frames when the indicator shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick to solve this issue is to create an empty view and use it as the cell's `accessoryView`. Do this only for the cells that don't have a detail disclosure.

The trick is setting the size of the view properly. A little trial and error should do it.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:...` method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = ... // get the cell
If (/* there is no detail disclosure */) {
    // Try different "width" value for this view to get the desired results
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)];
    cell.accessoryView = view;
}
```

Comment: interesting idea.  I'll probably go this route, although adding blank views isn't really my favorite option.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use different cells. One with the disclosure indicator, and one without. You then have complete control over the layout. And by using the cell reloading mechanism rather than the table reloading mechanism this is efficient.

Better than using blank views IMHO.